# Python cannot find the path to the data in the json module

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My efforts to make an interactive dictionary where the user can query the json data set have been thwarted by my incompetence; can someone please assist me.

As seen, I am working in the python directory and I am using python on windows.

**My code**

```
import json, os

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

def translate(word):
    return data(word)

word = input("enter word: ")

print(translate(word))
```

[The error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbFMb.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the json file in the same directory as the script?

Comment: Hi, yes I would say so. My json file path is -  C:\Python27\Lib\json and my script is in -  C:\Python27

Comment: The open function is only looking in the same directory, not in subdirectorys. So, if your script is in `C:\Python27`, than files in `C:\Python27\Lib` are not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the real path of `data.json` is first, one programatic option to do so is using [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), try this one:

```
import json, sys, os

def translate(word):
    return data(word)

try:
    print(os.path.abspath('data.json'))
    print(os.getcwd())
    data = json.load(open('data.json'))
    word = input("enter word: ")
    print(translate(word))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

And you'll realize `data.json` was not living where you're assuming.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I ran it, I got the following:                                            C:\Python27\data.json
C:\Python27
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'
enter word: novice

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/tst.py", line 13, in <module>
    word = input("enter word: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'novice' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @David Ok, so, here you go, that means when you're using 'data.json' in the open function the real path is trying to read is `C:\Python27\data.json`, now, if you're open the windows explorer and go there, does that file exist in that path? That's the reason of the error. So, you need to use the path where your 'data.json' is living. Assuming your path is c:\python27\lib\data.json you should use "c:\\python27\\lib\\data.json" in your open function. On the other hand, try to avoid always hardcoded paths like that and use [path module functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.json` is under lib `Lib`, the code might be like this:

```
import json, os

data = json.load(open(os.path.join('Lib', 'data.json')))

def translate(word):
    return data(word)

word = input("enter word: ")

print(translate(word))
```

Answer (score -1):

*import json, os*

Where is 'data.json' located? Unless data.json is beside the running
python interpreter the interpreter won't be able to find the file.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

*data = json.load(open('data.json'))*

The following won't work you're calling data as function. Try data[word]

*def translate(word): return data(word)*

*word = input("enter word: ")*

*print(translate(word))*